# Using Newtonsoft.JSON (JSON.net), how do I add a JArray, with child JObjects to an existing JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This is a C# application using the Newtonsoft.JSON library.

I have a JObject that is a search, to which I need to add a JArray, to which I need to add some more JObjects

This is what I need to add to my `search` object:

```
"sort": [
  {
    "_score": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to follow the example **[HERE](https://codecisions.com/how-to-build-custom-json-using-json-net/)**

I have tried this:

```
JProperty orderProperty = new JProperty("order","asc");
JObject scoreObject = new JObject("_score", orderProperty);
search.Add("sort", new JArray { new JObject { scoreObject } });
```

But this does not work, and I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.ArgumentException: Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.
```

This is a method that almost worked, but the JSON didn't come out correctly:

```
JProperty orderProperty = new JProperty("order","asc");
JObject scoreObject = new JObject();
scoreObject.Add(orderProperty);
search.Add("sort", new JArray { "_score", scoreObject });
```

And the JSON came out looking like this:

```
"sort":[
    "_score",{
        "order":"asc"
    }
],
```

---

**EDIT:**

I also tried this, but it came out with the same error:

```
search.Add("sort",new JArray {
    new JObject {
        new JObject {
            "_score", new JProperty("order", "asc")
        }
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the inner `JObject` with the property `order`.

Create the outer `JObject` with the property `_score`, which contains the inner `JObject`.

Create a `JArray` and add the outer `JObject` to it.

Add this `JArray` to your existing `search JObject` under the key `sort`.

```
JObject orderObject = new JObject();
orderObject.Add("order", "asc");

JObject scoreObject = new JObject();
scoreObject.Add("_score", orderObject);

JArray sortArray = new JArray();
sortArray.Add(scoreObject);

search.Add("sort", sortArray);
```